# Use LEFT JOIN Some to Many

Tags: php, mysql

```
clients
-----------------------
| job_no |  client    |
-----------------------
| 1      | North_1    |
| 2      | North_1    |
| 3      | North_1    |
| 4      | North_1    |
| 5      | North_2    |
| 6      | North_2    |
| 7      | North_2    |
| 8      | East       |
| 9      | East       |
| 10     | West       |
-----------------------

orders
-----------------------
| job_no |  order_no  |
-----------------------
| 1      | order_1    |
| 1      | order_2    |
| 5      | order_4    |
| 5      | order_5    |
| 5      | order_6    |
| 5      | order_7    |
| 5      | order_8    |
-----------------------
```

I have 2 tables (client and orders) and I need to retrieve the rows by client name (LIKE)?

I could do something very long winded like :-(

```
$sql_a = "SELECT job_no, client FROM clients WHERE client LIKE '%North%'";
$rows_a = fetchAll($sql_a);

foreach($rows_a as $rowsArray_a) {
    $sql_b = "SELECT order_no FROM orders WHERE job_no='$rowsArray_a['job_no']";
    $rows_b = fetchAll($sql_b);
    foreach($rows_b as $rowsArray_b) {
        $data[]=array('job'=>$rowsArray_a['job_no'], 'order'=>$rowsArray_b['order_no'], 'client'=>$rowsArray_a['client']
    }
}
```

to achieve a result that would eventually look something like:

```
Job     Order      Client
1       order_1    North_1
1       order_2    North_1
5       order_4    North_2
5       order_5    North_2
5       order_6    North_2
5       order_7    North_2
5       order_8    North_2
```

But is there a better way using either LEFT JOIN or even a LEFT JOIN SELECT, or even a SELECT in a SELECT?

I've tried

```
$sql = SELECT clients.job_no, clients.client, orders.job_no, orders.order_no FROM clients LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.job_no = clients.job_no WHERE clients.client LIKE '%North%'
```

All order data is NULL

and also

```
$sql = "SELECT clients.job_no, clients.client FROM clients LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.job_no = (SELECT o.job_no, o.order_no WHERE o.job_no = clients.job_no) WHERE clients.client LIKE '%North%'"
```

But getting a syntax error near WHERE clients.client LIKE '%North%'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.job_no,
  c.client,
  o.order_no
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.job_no = c.job_no
WHERE c.client LIKE '%North%'
```

You should add fields from `clients` and `orders` as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. works like a dream.  My actual query was a little more complex so will post my final solution for others, once tested.

Comment: @user3794393 If above solution solves your issue please accept his answer

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid  - is this a button I should press or a tick-box I should use somewhere to "please accept his answer", apologies I do not understand???

Comment: @user3794393: He is probably referring to [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It would help others to know if this answer helped you, or not (see also: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).  But, personally, i do not care much about you accepting this, or not , but it is informative when there are multiple answer to quickly pick a good one...

Comment: Apologies @MKhalidJunaid. I marked the score up, but did not know about clicking the tick to make green. Thanks again Luuk.

Answer (score 0):

From the above I have been able to extend the query to also include the order value, which can be zero: meaning you can apply seperate arguments to both tables in the query

```
SELECT
c.job_no,
c.client,
o.order_no
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.job_no = c.job_no
WHERE c.client LIKE '%North%'
AND o.order_value !=null
```